# Retrying request from Ember Data

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have an ember app with a rails backend.

I have a specific error that Rails can return (401) that I would like Ember to catch and act upon. In that case I would like to perform a custom method (which essentially modifies the request cookie) and then makes the request again.

Right now I am catching this error at the top level router and forcing the entire app the reload with window.location.reload(). Obviously this is a terrible hack. I was not able to get router.refresh() to work, but that would still be a hack anyway.

Ideally I would catch this much closer to the adapter so I can act on it. Perhaps I could catch this instead at the adapter level by overriding handleResponse(), but how would I retry the request from there?

http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html#method_handleResponse
handleResponse does pass along the requestData, but I would need some way to perform the request in the context of the adapter's methods, right?

Comment: I guess your server returns 401 when user is not athorized to make a request, am I right? If so, please tell how do you handle authorization: do you use ember-simple-auth or something else?

Comment: I have rolled my own auth solution. I store some user metadata in local storage. In addition Rails maintains a session. This problem comes up when the rails session has expired and local storage has not. This design is definitely not the best solution (I think I am going to remove the local storage part eventually), but thats how it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can handle this error in application route (what I did):

```
error: function (error, transition) {
 /**
  * Code below may vary depending on your server's response format
  */
  if (error.errors !== undefined) {
    for (var i = 0; i < error.errors.length; i++) {
      if (error.errors[i].status !== undefined) {
        if (parseInt(error.errors[i].status) === 401) {
          transition.abort(); //this line may not be needed in last versions, I'm not sure
          //Do what should be done, redirect to authentication for example
          //transition.retry(); should work too
          break;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It may look like "too high level", but it's how you handle errors in ember. Some time ago I wrote a [post](http://blog.gennady.pp.ua/how-to-handle-backend-errors-in-ember-js-properly/) about error handling, you may take a look if you are interested.
Of course you may want to extend an adapter to handle errors, but I would not suggest doing so. First, you will not have an access to route/controller inside adapter's methods. Second, it is not an "ember way". Adapter should return a promice, which will be rejected in case of error and it should not handle errors in any other way.

Comment: http://dpaste.com/19PTY4N your code could be also written like that. More emberish way.

Comment: This is very close to what I am doing, but it greatly helps. I was able to remove window.location.reload() and use transition.abort(); transition.retry(); to get my desired page reload to work. I'm still having trouble getting the error to trigger when I want. If I am on a page with the error and I click 'reload' in the browser, the error triggers. But if I click a link on the site that switches to another route the same error happens but is not caught by the error handler.

Comment: @Jono If error happens during model hook, It should be handled by error action. Note that error bubbles until it's handled. For example, if you have routes hierarchy: application/users/user, error may be handled by user route or users route or application route. This means if you defined error action on users route, ember may not call an error action of application route.

Comment: Like you I am catching this in the application controller. But still it only catches the first time - when the app loads. The second time (transition between routes) the error is thrown it does not catch. I have tried moving the error action to a lower route and the behaviour is the same. I have put the catch on every route, and the behaviour is the same. The most specific route catches, but only once.

Comment: @Jono did you try to remove transition.abort()? In latest ember version I had similar problems and removing that line fixed erors

Answer (score 0):

If route's model hook get's rejected it calls out error method

You could make a mixin and wrap it to your routes.

```
import RouteMixin from 'xx/mixins/route';

Ember.Route.extend(RouteMixin, {

})
```

And inside the RouteMixin add an action

```
error: function() {          
   // this.transitionTo('/not-found');
}
```

Arguments of error.

- Sever response
- Transition class
- Route related info

You could change request params and make re-route.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I am doing now. But its too high level. I am trying to handle this more transparently in the data layer instead of having to reload pages. This essentially breaks the single page app and all my unit tests.